Postgres SELECT hanging forever modifying the WHERE cause with only 1 minute difference
I have the problem exposed below.
I have got a table defined in this way:
CREATE TABLE opensearch.product (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    "timeStart" timestamp NOT NULL,
    "timeEnd" timestamp NULL,
    [...]
);

[...]
CREATE INDEX "idx_product_timeStart" ON opensearch.product USING btree ("timeStart");

The simple query below, modifying only one minute in the "timeStart" field (from 14:28:00.000 to 14:29:00.000), causes the database to hang forever.
Also, there are no records in the table with timeStart = NULL.
I will write below the two different version of the query, explained with EXPLAIN command (I think the difference is the core problem).
I am running postgres server 16 on Linux Rocky.
The query is stuck with IOWait event in pg_activity and causes the table to be locked.
I think there is some problem in the filesystem, but I don't know where to start the check. All I see is that there is no CPU or disk usage, so it looks completely hanged. There are also no other rows between 14:28:00.000 and 14:29:00.000!
I noticed also that if I remove " OR "timeStart" IS NULL", they both works correctly.
Where could I start to check?
This is the query in the working version, it takes only 1/100 of second.
-- this query below DOES NOT cause the db to hang
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM "opensearch"."product"
        WHERE "timeStart" < '2014-10-12 14:28:00.000'  OR "timeStart" IS NULL
        ORDER BY "timeStart" DESC LIMIT 10;
                                                        QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=15680.72..15680.74 rows=10 width=1837)
   ->  Sort  (cost=15680.72..15711.21 rows=12197 width=1837)
         Sort Key: "timeStart" DESC
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on product  (cost=117.46..15417.14 rows=12197 width=1837)
               Recheck Cond: (("timeStart" < '2014-10-12 14:28:00'::timestamp without time zone) OR ("timeStart" IS NULL))
               ->  BitmapOr  (cost=117.46..117.46 rows=12197 width=0)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "idx_product_timeStart"  (cost=0.00..109.54 rows=12197 width=0)
                           Index Cond: ("timeStart" < '2014-10-12 14:28:00'::timestamp without time zone)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "idx_product_timeStart"  (cost=0.00..1.82 rows=1 width=0)
                           Index Cond: ("timeStart" IS NULL)
(10 rows)

And this is the not-working verison:
psql=# -- this query below DOES hang forever!! the only difference: only one minute
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM "opensearch"."product"
        WHERE "timeStart" < '2014-10-12 14:29:00.000' OR "timeStart" IS NULL
        ORDER BY "timeStart" DESC LIMIT 10;
                                                        QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1507.75..15837.37 rows=10 width=1837)
   ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=1507.75..17480774.12 rows=12198 width=1837)
         Sort Key: "timeStart" DESC
         Presorted Key: "timeStart"
         ->  Index Scan Backward using "idx_product_timeStart" on product  (cost=0.56..17480246.21 rows=12198 width=1837)
               Filter: (("timeStart" < '2014-10-12 14:29:00'::timestamp without time zone) OR ("timeStart" IS NULL))
(6 rows)


Id the table has 10 rows with null timeStart, then those will be selected and the condition timeStart < '2014-10-12 14:29:00.000' should be ignored. Is this correct?

@TheImpaler actually there are no records in the table with timeStart = NULL.

@TheImpaler's point being (I assume) that you should probably use ORDER BY "timeStart" DESC NULLS LAST while null values are possible. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511492/939860

@max_s If that's the case then the predicate OR "timeStart" IS NULL should be removed. With that predicate removed the optimization is trivial: just add an index on (timeStart).

@TheImpaler I actually cannot modify the query since it comes from an external source, but thank you for the hint. The index is already present, but I don't think there is a problem of optimization: the query is hanging for days and looks completely blocked.

As the plans are so different it likely thinks the number of records that match are going to be (vastly) different. Have you run a VACUUM ANALYZE on the table recently? If it is a big table you may want to up the STATISTICS target on that field and ANALYZE again and see if that makes any difference?
